# foreach retornando dado vazio inexistente

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="perguntas.php" method="GET">
    <fieldset>
        <?php
        $StringPerguntaLoja = "SELECT *
        FROM sug_pergunta_fixa AS p
        inner join sug_area as a
        ON a.sa_id = p.pf_area
        WHERE pf_status=0";
        $QueryPerguntaLoja  = $conn->query($StringPerguntaLoja);

        $StringOpcaoRespFixa = "SELECT * FROM sug_opcao_resp_fixa WHERE opresp_fixa_status = 0";
        $QueryOpcaoRespFixa  = $conn->query($StringOpcaoRespFixa);

        $Repostas = [];
        $Perguntas = [];

        while($Perguntas[] = $QueryPerguntaLoja->fetch_assoc());
        while($Repostas[] = $QueryOpcaoRespFixa->fetch_assoc());

        foreach ($Perguntas as $rowPergunta) {
        echo"<div class='panel panel-default'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
            ".$rowPergunta['sa_desc']."
        </div>
    </div>";

        echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>".$rowPergunta['pf_desc']."</div>
        <div class='panel-body'>";

            foreach ($Repostas as $row_resposta) {

            echo"<input type='radio'
                        name='".$rowPergunta['pf_id']."'
            value='".$row_resposta["opresp_fixa_valor"]."'>
            ".$row_resposta["opresp_fixa_desc"];

            }
            echo"</div>";

        echo"</div>";
        }
        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">CANCELAR</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">SALVAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Ele retorna um formulário com umas perguntas e uns radios:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Duvida:

No final do radio que são 3 opções esta exibindo uma quarta vazia, e como podem ver na imagem na pergunta também, o que poderia estar causando isso?

> var_dump perguntas

```
array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_desc"]=> string(15) "LIMPEZA DA LOJA" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["pf_desc"]=> string(19) "FOLHETOS DE OFERTAS" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_desc"]=> string(26) "SINALIZAÇÃO DAS SEÇÕES" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["pf_desc"]=> string(20) "CARRINHOS DE COMPRAS" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["pf_desc"]=> string(14) "ESTACIONAMENTO" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["pf_desc"]=> string(23) "BALCÕES DE ATENDIMENTO" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["pf_desc"]=> string(19) "ENTREGA A DOMICILIO" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "8" ["pf_desc"]=> string(18) "CARTAZES DE PREÇO" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "1" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["sa_desc"]=> string(4) "LOJA" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["pf_desc"]=> string(9) "QUALIDADE" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "2" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["sa_desc"]=> string(8) "PRODUTOS" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["pf_desc"]=> string(9) "VARIEDADE" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "2" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["sa_desc"]=> string(8) "PRODUTOS" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "11" ["pf_desc"]=> string(7) "PREÇOS" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "2" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["sa_desc"]=> string(8) "PRODUTOS" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "12" ["pf_desc"]=> string(9) "AGILIDADE" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "13" ["pf_desc"]=> string(9) "ATENÇÃO" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "14" ["pf_desc"]=> string(8) "SIMPATIA" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["pf_desc"]=> string(10) "EDUCAÇÃO" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "16" ["pf_desc"]=> string(6) "CAIXAS" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "17" ["pf_desc"]=> string(8) "AÇOUGUE" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "18" ["pf_desc"]=> string(7) "PADARIA" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["pf_desc"]=> string(8) "GERENCIA" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "20" ["pf_desc"]=> string(10) "SEGURANÇA" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "21" ["pf_desc"]=> string(14) "GUARDA VOLUMES" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "22" ["pf_desc"]=> string(26) "ATENDIMENTO FRENTE DE LOJA" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "23" ["pf_desc"]=> string(23) "FRIOS/QUEIJOS/EMBUTIDOS" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }


array(7) { ["pf_id"]=> string(2) "24" ["pf_desc"]=> string(14) "FRUTAS/LEGUMES" ["pf_area"]=> string(1) "3" ["pf_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["sa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["sa_desc"]=> string(11) "ATENDIMENTO" ["sa_status"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

> var_dump resposta

```
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
LOJA : FOLHETOS DE OFERTAS
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
LOJA : SINALIZAÇÃO DAS SEÇÕES
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
LOJA : CARRINHOS DE COMPRAS
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
LOJA : ESTACIONAMENTO
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
LOJA : BALCÕES DE ATENDIMENTO
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
LOJA : ENTREGA A DOMICILIO
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
LOJA : CARTAZES DE PREÇO
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
PRODUTOS : QUALIDADE
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
PRODUTOS : VARIEDADE
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
PRODUTOS : PREÇOS
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : AGILIDADE
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : ATENÇÃO
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : SIMPATIA
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : EDUCAÇÃO
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : CAIXAS
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : AÇOUGUE
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : PADARIA
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : GERENCIA
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : SEGURANÇA
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : GUARDA VOLUMES
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : ATENDIMENTO FRENTE DE LOJA
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : FRIOS/QUEIJOS/EMBUTIDOS
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
ATENDIMENTO : FRUTAS/LEGUMES
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
:
 ÓTIMO    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(6) "ÓTIMO" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "5" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  REGULAR    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }  RUIM    array(4) { ["opresp_fixa_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["opresp_fixa_desc"]=> string(4) "RUIM" ["opresp_fixa_valor"]=> string(1) "1" ["opresp_fixa_status"]=> string(1) "0" }      NULL
```

Comment: Pode postar para nós o var_dump/print_r do array que roda nos foreachs?

Comment: @BrunoFolle Adicionado o var_dump na pergunta

Comment: A sua consulta "SELECT * FROM sug_opcao_resp_fixa WHERE opresp_fixa_status = 0"; Não estaria retornando uma tupla vazia? Fazendo preencher seu array com uma linha vazia?

Comment: Parece que há uma chave a mais no final do seu array. Já tentou utlizar `if(isset($row_resposta["opresp_fixa_valor"]) && $row_resposta["opresp_fixa_valor"] != ""){/*lógica para criar input*/}` ?

Comment: @MarcosMarques não, já validei isso

Comment: @BrunoFolle Continuou mostrando os vazios, que estranho

Comment: Os caras da -1 só por esporte, só pode ser, precisando achar a solução de um problema e os caras zoam a pergunta, aff.

Comment: o foreach está fazendo isso porque o array tem 4 chaves, algum lixo ta vindo junto

Comment: @BrunoFolle Alterei a estrutura,era realmente algo no while ou no forech ou array, não entendi onde, mais deu certo, obrigado pela atenção. Resposta adicionada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solução:

```
                                <?php
                                $StringPerguntaLoja = "SELECT * 
                                FROM sug_pergunta_fixa AS p
                                left join sug_area as a
                                ON a.sa_id = p.pf_area
                                WHERE pf_status=0";
                                $QueryPerguntaLoja  = $conn->query($StringPerguntaLoja);

                                while($rowPergunta = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryPerguntaLoja)){


                                    $VarArea     =  $rowPergunta['sa_desc'];
                                    $VarPergunta =  $rowPergunta['pf_desc'];
                                    $VarId       =  $rowPergunta['pf_id'];

                                    echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>
                                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                                        <span class='label label-primary'>".$VarArea."</span> ".$VarPergunta."</div>
                                        <div class='panel-body'>";


                                            $StringOpcaoRespFixa = "SELECT * FROM sug_opcao_resp_fixa WHERE opresp_fixa_status = 0"; 
                                            $QueryOpcaoRespFixa  = $conn->query($StringOpcaoRespFixa);
                                            while($rowResposta = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryOpcaoRespFixa)){

                                                $VarValor =   $rowResposta["opresp_fixa_valor"];
                                                $VarOpcao =   $rowResposta["opresp_fixa_desc"];

                                                echo "<input 
                                                type='radio' 
                                                name='$VarId' 
                                                id='$VarId' 
                                                value='$VarValor'>$VarOpcao &nbsp; ";

                                            }


                                            echo"</div>";
                                            echo"</div>";
                                        }
```